# Could external factors affect fancybox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Sorry I can't add any links as this is quite a general query and I was just wondering whether apache/network settings could afftect fancybox events and if so could you point me in the right direction?

I have two pages which are exactly the same but one is hosted on a dev.mydomain and the other is www.mydomain. The page allows the user to amend something in a fancybox iframe and then click save. This then saves the data via a post request and closes the fancybox. It works perfectly in dev but doesn't in live. This has been tested in the same browser on different tabs.

Any ideas? Or even could you please rule out my theory if you think it must be something within the code?

Rachel

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean the lightbox doesn't show, or submitting the update form doesn't produce the results you expect?

Comment: Since it all happens at the client, the server environment shouldn't matter.  Unless the server is sending different files to the client.

Comment: same origin policy would make a difference for AJAX requests.

Comment: it just doesn't close on save

Comment: i'm using an iframe on fancybox with a form and the i post the form back and then fancybox should close. it works in the dev environment but not in live. I eventually get a white screen.

Comment: can anyone shed light on when I should use an iframe and when I should use inine options for a form? I think that there's an issue with event delegation on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible for a server to disallow functionality or transmission of data from an iframe, though I have no evidence to support that claim. If the site is an aboslute replica, it could be a pathing issue. Do an inspect in firefox, and find out what happens in the console when you click "save". Is a request made to the server? If so, open it and check the posted data, and the response.

I believe this is the case (not allowed) because this creates a possibility for XSS aka Cross Site Scripting. I'd recommend saving to a database, myself.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I can only make guesses.

I would assume that your save buttons makes an ajax call. After the ajax call completes ( the 'success' function ) you are closing the fancybox. My best guess is that the ajax call is failing, so your success function is never called.

Try using Firebug or Fiddler to monitor your ajax calls. Maybe your call is going to the wrong url for your production environment?